# Bootstrap div alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar, col

I'm having issue trying to align my div in Bootstrap 3.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

I have worked with pull and push but I guess I'm not good enough with it.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 blue">
            blue
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 red">
            red
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 orange">
            orange
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 green">
            green
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 purple">
            purple
        </div>             
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bva5z74w/1/

Comment: And your code is? your try?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bva5z74w/1/ :)

Comment: The only way I see with bootstraps is duplicate the orange div check this http://www.bootply.com/QJHocWWfGL#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was watching this to see if anyone would come answer the obvious: don't use bootstrap push and pull for this. Use float right and no floats. Blue must be taller than red at the min-width, other than that I think this will work smoothly.

[image]

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/degeju/1/**

**CSS:**

```
.blue {
    background: blue
}
.red {
    background: red
}
.orange {
    background: orange
}
.green {
    background: green
}
.purple {
    background: purple
}
.red,
.blue,
.green,
.orange,
.purple {
    height: 50px
}

@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .blue {
        height: 600px;
        float: right;
    }
    .red {
        height: 300px;
        float: none;
    }
    .orange {
        height: 400px;
        float: right;
    }
    .green {
        height: 200px;
        float: none;
    }
    .purple {
        height: 200px;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 blue">
            blue
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 red">
            red
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 orange">
            orange
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 green">
            green
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 purple">
            purple
        </div>             
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you have will work perfectly, just remove the `pull` on the purple block:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 blue">
            blue
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 red">
            red
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 orange">
            orange
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 green">
            green
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 purple">
            purple
        </div>             
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/dMNG75tSf0

Edit:

The `float` on the left elements is causing them to collapse to fit their contents. However, with media queries you can set the height to be the same height as the adjacent right element.

```
@media (max-width:1199px) {
    .red {
        height: 360px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .red {
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

The obvious drawback is this limits the fix to browsers that support media queries. Therefore, [Christina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596950/bootstrap-div-alignement-issue/26597861#answer-26600521) is better, assuming it works consistently across browsers.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm trying to do is to get the green div below the red one.

It worked for you because you put the same height for every div...

Comment: @fred.kassi I don't think setting an explicit height is a good idea, unless the height is the same for all of the blocks. You could, remove the height property from my CSS and put the pull back on the purple and it will work: http://www.bootply.com/2mOEddHjPz

Comment: If you want the column to "vertically fill" the empty space, you can just set the `background-color` of the row to the color of the shortest column.

Comment: I filled the div with the same content (in term of size) I have... You can see that there's still a problem with the sidebar http://jsfiddle.net/bva5z74w/2/

Comment: @fred.kassi The `float` that Bootstrap uses forces the container to collapse like that. You can easily override with [media queries](http://jsfiddle.net/bva5z74w/4/), however.

Answer (score -1):

div has a display type "block", by default this means that each div will be shown below another div.

this means that someway you've changed some of the css, specifically with floats or display:inline.

if you're not sure how to find and change this you can always make sure each div has width:100%;

that will make sure the div catches the whole width of it's parent container.

Comment: How this answer the question? At least did you know bootstrap?